# Pentaho cookies with Rest Client Transformation entry

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle, data-integration

Is there an option to set cookies while using rest client in Pentaho 5.1?

I read a couple of blogs and it wasnt mentioned anywhere.

I have tried using curl using shell job entry. Got the cookie and used it in my next curl to get data.

I need to do a similar process using rest client transformation entry.

Please let me know if there are any leads I can follow.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29437154/run-pdi-jobs-using-web-services

Answer (score 0):

i dont know if you can do that with this step, but with the **http client step** you can set you own http request headers. This works because i use this way.

if you can use the http client step instead the rest client do this:

add a new **Script step** (the javascript step) and add this js code to your trans (these are sample headers, the most interesting for you is the last one):

```
//set the headers to next step
var header_accept_charset  = "utf-8";
var header_cache_control = "max-age=0";
var header_user_agent = "batman browser";
lal = "lalvalue_fooo";
lel = "lelvalue_meeeh";
var cookie = "lol="+ lol +"; lal="+ lal;
```

Now make sure the vars are passed **to the next step, the http client** (click on get variables to fill the rows of "fields"), this should works.

The cookie is just another request header, a string simply built with the concatenation of variables and values with semicolons.

PD:Maybe this method works with the Rest Client step, if works also with this step let me know, i am interested to know that.